# How to get a loop for a differential equation system?

Tags: procedural-programming, infinite-loop

I would like to know how can I obtained a loop of this system

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n0 = 3;

Nmax = 5;

A[1] = {{0.5218440349603428`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 
    0.03043455783984461`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 
    1.`, -0.5733456379977422`, 1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 
    1.`, -0.1691687728719371`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    1.`, -0.6766851294154084`}};

A[2] = {{0.5920373626109177`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 
    0.060631154827360145`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 
    1.`, -0.02863887747946947`, 1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 
    1.`, -0.35285446053637504`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 
    0.36012246351093635`}};

A[3] = {{0.67202601044949`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {1.`, -0.3920737805614185`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 
    1.`, -0.05678745158627674`, 1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 
    0.5330963738805732`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 
    0.11619190701387883`}};

\[Psi]ini = Table[KroneckerDelta[n0 - i], {i, 1, Nmax}];

usol[1] = 
  NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t], t] == 
     A[1].\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == \[Psi]ini}, \[Psi], {t, 0, 10}];

usol[2] = 
  NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t], t] == A[2].\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == 
     usol[1][10]}, \[Psi], {t, 10, 20}];

usol[3] = 
  NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t], t] == A[3].\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == 
     usol[2][20]}, \[Psi], {t, 20, 30}];
```

In this form works but I would like to do in loop. Actually, I would like too joined all the usol[i] and plot them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

"12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"

Clear["Global`*"]

n0 = 3;
Nmax = 5;

A[1] = {{0.5218440349603428`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 0.03043455783984461`,
     1.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 1.`, -0.5733456379977422`, 1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 
    1.`, -0.1691687728719371`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    1.`, -0.6766851294154084`}};
A[2] = {{0.5920373626109177`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 
    0.060631154827360145`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 1.`, -0.02863887747946947`, 
    1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 1.`, -0.35285446053637504`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    1.`, 0.36012246351093635`}};
A[3] = {{0.67202601044949`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {1.`, -0.3920737805614185`, 
    1.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 1.`, -0.05678745158627674`, 1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 
    1.`, 0.5330963738805732`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 
    0.11619190701387883`}};
```

Replace `ψini` with `usol[0][t]` that is constant for all `t`.

```
usol[0][t_] = Table[KroneckerDelta[n0 - i], {i, 1, Nmax}];
```

Then,

```
(usol[#] = 
     NDSolveValue[{I D[ψ[t], t] == A[#] . ψ[t], ψ[0] == 
        usol[# - 1][10 (# - 1)]}, ψ, {t, 10 (# - 1), 10 #}]) & /@ 
  Range[3];
```

**EDIT:** Assuming that you want to plot the absolute value of the complex numbers,

```
Column[
 Table[
  ListLinePlot[
   Abs@Transpose@Table[usol[n][t],
      {t, 10 (n - 1), 10 n, 0.1}],
   DataRange -> {10 (n - 1), 10 n},
   PlotLabel ->
    Style[StringForm["Abs[usol[``]", n], 14, Bold],
   PlotLegends -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> Medium],
  {n, 1, 3}]]
```

[image]

```
Legended[
 Show[
  Table[
   ListLinePlot[Abs@Transpose@Table[usol[n][t],
       {t, 10 (n - 1), 10 n, 0.1}],
    DataRange -> {10 (n - 1), 10 n}],
   {n, 1, 3}],
  PlotRange -> All,
  ImageSize -> Large],
 LineLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], Range[5]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon this is the loop which I need. But now I would like to plot usol[#] but the command "Plot" doesn´t work. How can I plot them?